# Java Web Start AccessControlException LoggingPermission

Tags: java, permissions, java-web-start, code-access-security

I get the following exception when running my JWS application, even though I signed all my jars and I added localhost to the Exception Site List.

```
Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for: http://localhost/page/CWSExecution.jar
Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: http://localhost/page/CWSExecution.jar
starting
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.checkPermission(LogManager.java:1414)
    at java.util.logging.Handler.checkPermission(Handler.java:301)
    at java.util.logging.Handler.setLevel(Handler.java:256)
    at fr.dauphine.wscn.WindowHandler.configure(LogFrame.java:106)
```

This is the only warning I get before launching the app:

[image: Figure 1]

Also, if I click on "More Information", I can see the certificate I have created.

I actually adapted this [Java log: Log and Window(JFrame, frame) example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/JavalogLogandWindowJFrameframe.htm) to work within my JWS app. The error is caused in the "configure" method:

```
setLevel(level != null ? Level.parse(level) : Level.INFO);
```

Comment: *"..even though I signed all my jars.."* Did you generate the code signing certificate using the SDK?  Is it a proper certificate from Verisign or Thawte?

Comment: I did it myself, so it is not a proper certificate. I thought that it would ask to the user to trust or not on my certificate, and then, let my app run depending on the choice.

Comment: *"..it is not a proper certificate."*  These days, an app. signed with such a certificate won't be launched at all.